# Setting Pokemon stats

Tags: python, object-oriented, pokemon

I set the stats (.ie. name, attack, defense, HP) in the `__init__` method. However, I have chosen to build the `self.attacks` dictionary with a separate method.

```
class Pokemon(object):

     def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, HP):
                self.name = name
                self.attack = attack
                self.defense = defense
                self.HP = HP
                self.attacks = {}

     def Moves(self,move_1,damage_1,move_2,damage_2):
                self.attacks[move_1] = damage_1
                self.attacks[move_2] = damage_2
```

```
pikachu = Pokemon('Pikachu',40,10,50)
pidgey = Pokemon('Pidgey',50,30,60)

pikachu.Moves('tackle',50,'thunderbolt',70)
pidgey.Moves('gust',80,'tackle',50)
```

The code works as expected but I'm not sure if this proper use of classes. I believe it is and have seen some examples do similar things. I just wanted to check if I am headed in the right direction.

Edit:  The reason I would like to know is because the `Pokemon` will be getting many more attributes and I need a way to assign those attributes in groups to avoid assigning fifty or so variables every time I create a new instance of `Pokemon`.

Comment: Will the Pokemon eventually have multiple attacks and defenses? If so, the class structure would be a little more complicated, with each attack/defense being added dynamically as its own callable method.

Comment: Your indentation is misleading. Could you please fix it ? As it is, your code is broken hence is off-topic here. Thanks

Comment: Was there a particular reason to avoid the more straightforward `pikachu = Pokemon('Pikachu', 40, 10, 50, {'tackle': 50, 'thunderbolt': 70})`? Without knowing *why* you did it it's hard to say whether it's a good idea, but if you didn't have a reason it's probably not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I plan to add many more attributes and didn't want to put it all in one line. So my plan was group the assignments with functions. But I didn't know if this was an approved method or not though. The `Pokemon` itself will have several more attributes and each `move` that `Pokemon` has will also have several more attributes.

Comment: @Ryan Mills yes eventually I will have more attack/defenses as well as adding a leveling system for the pokemon.

Comment: In that case your *"add two moves by passing individual attributes of each"* is going to scale *really* poorly. The OOP way to do it might be to pass in `..., {'tackle': Move(40), 'thunderbolt': Move(70)}` and allow for extension and specialisation of the move objects later. But please [edit] to provide more context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so `..., {'tackle': Move(40), 'thunderbolt': Move(70)}` is = to `'tackle' = Move (40)`? So make each move an instance of `Move ()`? That does seem much more scalable. I would have to keep up with a giant dictionary the way I was going try. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, or `Move('tackle', 40)` to keep the name together with it.

Comment: And also `Move` would remain a function of `Pokemon` and not its own class. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to step away from programming and design your classes.
Pokemon stats aren't just one number. And so you should design for this.

First things first, [Pokemon have multiple stats](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Statistic#List_of_stats), the main ones are:

- Each Pokemon of the same breed have the same [base stats](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Base_stats).
  Say you have two Pikachu, their base stats are *exactly the same*.
  And so you should define this on a Pokemon's class.
- They have 'genes', better know as [IVs - individual values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values).
  These change for each and every Pokemon, two Pikachu are unlikely to have the same IVs.
  They also don't change, ever. And so it'd be a good idea to make these immutable.
- They learn things by fighting, and gain [EVs - effort values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values).
  These aren't immutable all the time, but have a limit, and become immutable at that point.
- Pokemon have a nature, which also change a Pokemon's stats.

And so, if you want the program to be correct, you need to correctly handle the above.
But you need to handle all of them differently:

- For base stats, you want to use [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).
- For IVs, you want to use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), or just a tuple.
- For EVs, you want to have a user defined type.

And so you don't need to take 50 arguments in the creation of a Pokemon. You need 4 arguments, and if you want to pass the moves, 5.
To start you off you'd need something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Stats = namedtuple('Stats', 'hp attack defense sp_atk sp_def speed')


# TODO: add limits on input
class EV(object):
    def __init__(self, hp, attack, defense, sp_atk, sp_def, speed):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.sp_atk = sp_atk
        self.sp_def = sp_def
        self.speed = speed


class Pokemon(object):
    _base_stats = Stats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    def __init__(self, iv, ev, nature, level):
        # TODO: check input is within correct bounds
        self._iv = Stats(*iv)
        self._ev = EV(*ev)
        self._nature = nature
        self.level = level
        # TODO: take more data, such as the pokemon's name.

    @property
    def max_hp(self):
        base = self._base_stats.hp
        iv = self._iv.hp
        ev = self._ev.hp
        level = self.level
        return int(((2 * base + iv + int(ev/4)) * level) / 100) + level + 10

    def _calculate_stat(self, stat):
        base = getattr(self._base_stats, stat)
        iv = getattr(self._iv, stat)
        ev = getattr(self._ev, stat)
        level = self.level
        # TODO: correct nature
        nature = 1
        return int((int(((2 * base + iv + int(ev/4)) * level) / 100) + 5) * nature)

    @property
    def attack(self):
        return self._calculate_stat('attack')

    @property
    def defense(self):
        return self._calculate_stat('defense')


class Pikachu(object):
    _base_stats = Stats(35, 55, 40, 50, 50, 90)


def pokemon(base, *args, **kwargs):
    return type('Pokemon', (base, Pokemon), dict())(*args, **kwargs)


pikachu = pokemon(Pikachu, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], None, 100)
print(pikachu.max_hp)
print(pikachu.attack)
```

Even if you don't use the previous, then I'd still recommend that you move the data into smaller more logical datatypes.
But either way you should want to then change the way you're storing your moves.
Each move should be an object, it has a name, damage, type, miss chance, special animation. You need to contain all of this in each move.
But you also need to have an instance of each move, so that every move in the game doesn't share the same PP.
And so to create each move, you may want to do the same as above with the `Pikachu` class.
After this, it'd make more sense to store these instances in a list rather than a dictionary.

And so you should instead have something like:

```
class Tackle(object):
    name = 'tackle'
    damage = 70

pikachu = pokemon(..., [Tackle()])
```

Going further, if this is too static, then you can use `type` to define these classes. And allow you to off-load storing the data in a database.

You should want to take the moves in the constructor of the class as it *normally* makes saving and loading game state easier.
If you did want to keep your `Moves` function then you should change it to `add_move` and only take one move, *not* two.

Comment: @Peulonrayz Thank you so much!! This answers my question perfectly! I think I was trying to start with small stuff and work my way up and should have been doing the opposite. Thanks a million!!!!    Also, thank you for such a detailed response.